# Union of two Sets Java Set<T>

Tags: java, set, union

I'm working on Java homework right now and I've run into a bit of an issue; trying to find the Union between two sets.

My professor described the Union as

> The union of two sets A and B is the set obtained by combining the
>   members of each with out allowing multiplicity.

I don't quite understand what he means by not allowing multiplicity.

While searching google I found that a Union is basically just combing the two, which shouldn't be hard, but I keep getting errors that I do not quite understand.

I'll post everything having to do with the code required below.

```
public class Set<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    // A list of elements contained in the set
    private ArrayList<T> elements;

    // Creates an empty set
    public Set()
    {
        elements = new ArrayList();
    }

    public Set<T> union(Set<T> s)
    {
        // code here             
    }
}
```

Every time I try to return anything it tells me it is not a compatible type because the instance variable is an `ArrayList` and `Union` is a `Set`. Has anyone done this before or can help with some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a set is a collection of **unique** elements. Not allowing multiplicity means that elements may **not** be repeated.

However, this is not a restriction of an `ArrayList`, so a set that wraps around an `ArrayList` requires some extra logic to ensure it has no two elements for which `.equals()` evaluates to true.

A general outline for how to implement `union()` is to loop through all elements in both sets. However, before adding an element to your new set, make sure there is no element already in the set to which it is equal.

Comment: Thank you, by reading this I was able to create a more efficient code, and I also realized what was causing my error.